# state of art rating system in php

Tags: php, rating

I am a programmer .I want to know how to implement * rating in php.Just tell me the steps

Comment: What do you want to implement?  More details would definitely be helpful.

Comment: I am a programmer too.

Comment: @kevin: I'm so B-sodding the heck out of you! Or something.

Comment: Raise your hand if you're a programmer.

Comment: Really poor question. Would and should be getting plenty of down votes, mine included if I had 13 more reputation =P

Answer (score 3):

Not quite sure what you're talking about, so I'll give my best shot.

If you're talking about having a 5-star/10-star (etc) rating system, optimally, you should probably use a database backend and a jQuery frontend. In the database, you can store the stars as an tinyint (values 1-255), and you can use jQuery to:

- Send an AJAX request to the server
  when the user rates an item
- Display the stars so they're quite pretty and attractive, by utilizing their plugins and so forth

Depending on how you want to accomplish this, you may have a boolean stored in the session which checks if the user has rated an item or not; this is to prevent someone from rating an item over 9000 times.